# How to add custom information in detail pane of win vista and win 7 using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-7, windows-vista, .net-2.0

i have a file type for my application for which i want to show some custom information in Organize\Deatails Pane in windows explorer. Like for a word file it shows author and stuff similarly i have some custom information for my file which i want to show.

Anybody with idea on how can i do it?

Comment: how to add new attributes too the detail pane programatically

Comment: what i have know in my search so far is that i will need to implement some COM interfaces and extend IPreview:GetDetailsEx i have so far no idea on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PropertyGrid like VS does.

If that's not good enough, then you can use custom components.

Comment: i am a bit of a rookie, can you please elaborate

Comment: Read this page. It tells what is PropertyGrid and how to use it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/9fd3097a-9578-4824-8ced-054f41e2f7ab

Comment: nayan the above link, is this another way of doing the same?

Comment: i dont want a propety grid because i want the info to show on Windows Shell Details Pane. but you are right one way to show this could be to put property grid control on preview handler, but thats not details pane. so i guess left is to use custom components as u said above do you mean COM by that?

Comment: Yes, COM will be involved for Shell programming. If I find something, I'll post it here.

Comment: More specifically, this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/namespcextguide1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i have found that it can be through Property Handler. Currently i am researching on it will post the details here when i am done. In xp IColumnHandler was used to do this but since vista property handler are needed.